# How to save user define path into a variable?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

How  to save user define path into a variable  in Perl and use that variable in other places in script so if user gives a new path it will update the path each place where that variable is used.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, you could e.g. use command line parameters, environment variables, or a config file. What is the "bioinformatics" tag about?

Comment: Because I am student of bioinformatics and may be other bioinformatician can help me that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing here is the standard behaviour of a variable. So I have to wonder if I'm missing something.

```
my $default_path = '/the/default/path';

print "Enter your path [$default_path]: ";
chomp(my $user_path = <STDIN>);

my $path = $user_path // $default_path;

print "The path we'll use is: $path";

# And then, much later in the program...

my $filename = 'somefile.txt';
open my $fh, '>', "$path/$filename"
  or die "Cannot open $path/$filename: $!";
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working properly

Comment: But if there is a shell script link with this Perl Script and I want to use this user define path in Perl script and also in Shell script. what changes are required?

Comment: @RochiSaurabh: If you have further requirements that you omitted from this question, then it's best to post a new question with full details.